# Error message with SQL code

Tags: mysql

I need some help with a code in MySQL server. I keep getting this error:

Failed to execute SQL : SQL

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME) AS INSTRUCTOR_NAME, 
FROM 
    INSTRUCTOR 
LEFT JOIN 
    APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR 
    ON INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID=APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID 

UNION 

SELECT 
    CONCAT(INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME) AS INSTRUCTOR_NAME, 
FROM 
    INSTRUCTOR 
RIGHT JOIN 
    APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR 
    ON INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID=APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR.Instructor_ID;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM INSTRUCTOR LEFT JOIN APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR ON
>   INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID=APPROV' at line 1

I have double checked table and field names and done about an hour of research but everything I read indicates that there is not a problem with the code.

Comment: Any reason you tagged this with SQL Server as well as MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comma after both occurrences of `INSTRUCTOR_NAME`:

This:

```
SELECT CONCAT(INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME) AS INSTRUCTOR_NAME,
```

Should be:

```
SELECT CONCAT(INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME) AS INSTRUCTOR_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need commas between the `SELECT` and `FROM` statements.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME) AS INSTRUCTOR_NAME 
FROM 
    INSTRUCTOR 
LEFT JOIN 
    APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR 
    ON INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID=APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID 

UNION 

SELECT 
    CONCAT(INSTRUCTOR.FIRST_NAME, INSTRUCTOR.LAST_NAME) AS INSTRUCTOR_NAME 
FROM 
    INSTRUCTOR 
RIGHT JOIN 
    APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR 
    ON INSTRUCTOR.INSTRUCTOR_ID=APPROVED_INSTRUCTOR.Instructor_ID;
```